# How do I route /user/id to user.cshtml

Tags: c#, .net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-routing

I have a file called *Pages/user.cshtml* and *Pages/user.cshtml.cs* which contains the below.

It executes fine when I visit `/user?id=123` however I can't figure out how to make `/user/123` work.

I get nothing but 404s. I read over this page

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1

But I still can't figure it out.

I tried this route without any luck

```
app.UseMvc(routes => { routes.MapRoute("User", "User/{id}", new { action = "User" }); });
```

user.cshtml.cs

```
public class UserModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet(int id)
    {
        @ViewData["Title"] = id.ToString();
```

Comment: @mjwills doesn't exist. I had an idea how to do this with mvc3 on .net but 4 in dotnet core has me confused. If you type in `dotnet new razor` you'll essentially have what I'm working with.

Comment: @Nkosi I am looking at this page now https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/index?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio#custom-routes I see it suggest `@page "{id}"` but for the moment I'm not sure how to get the value/string

Comment: You add `@page "{id}"` to the Page's *cshtml* and include the parameter in the action as you didi above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Use the `@page` directive to:
>
> - Append parameters to a page's default route. For example, an ID
>     parameter, `id`, can be required for a page with `@page "{id}"`.

Reference [Introduction to Razor Pages in ASP.NET Core:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio#custom-routes)

So as I mentioned in the comments, you add `@page "{id}"` to the Page's *cshtml*

*User.cshtml*

```
@page {id:int}
@model UserModel

<html>
<body>
    ...
```

and include the parameter in the action as you did above

*User.cshtml.cs*

```
public class UserModel : PageModel {
    public void OnGet(int id) {

        //...

    }
}
```